# ComboBox locks at application start

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Ok, this is a strange one (or I'm doing something stupidly).
I have a WPF combobox which is populated with a string array on form load (app start).
This part works fine. The sticky bit is when I try to alter any of the information within said combobox. The debug says that it is changing but nothing is being shown visually.

```
// Populate the combobox:
private void ComboBlocks()
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    string[,] _tmp = _kits.BlockIDNames;
    string[] _tmp1 = new string[_tmp.GetLength(0)];

    for (int i = 0; i < _tmp.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        _tmp1[i] = _tmp[i, 0] + " - " + _tmp[i, 1];
    }

    foreach (string s in _tmp1)
    {
        string[] _tmpS1 = s.Split(new char[] { '-' });
        int _tmpS2 = Convert.ToInt32(_tmpS1[0].Trim());
        bool _banneditem = _cbi.BannedItemExists(_tmpS2);
        if (_banneditem == true)
            AddComboItem(s, true);
        else
            AddComboItem(s);
    }

    if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;            
}

// Add item to combobox:
private void AddComboItem(string _text,bool _redtext = false)
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });

    TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
    text.Text = _text;

    if (_redtext == true)
        text.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    else
        text.Foreground = Brushes.Black;

    grid.Children.Add(text);
    Grid.SetColumn(text, 0);

    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
    comboBoxItem.Content = grid;
    comboBoxItem.Tag = _text;

    comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBoxItem);
}
```

Also, I am fairly new to C# so if there is anything that I'm doing wrong/inefficiently, please point it out.

Many thanks.

EDIT: Iterating through each one and changing the text value would probably be just as much work as it gets its information from another array. It would have to check for each item in the array and if it exists, colour it red, if it doesn't, colour it black.

Comment: When you say, "alter any of the information within said combobox", what do you mean?  Are you talking about typing in the combobox, but your combobox isn't auto-completing?

Comment: No, I'm grabbing the contents from a class. I have another form that changes the information within that class then calls ComboBlocks() again. The items in the combobox don't change at all - if they're red they stay red and likewise for black.

Comment: I have even added a button to the same form on which the combobox sits. This button calls ComboBlocks() directly yet still nothing happens. If I tell the button to "comboBox1.Items.Clear()" it works but this doesn't get me any closer to solving this.

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but in regards to asking about efficiency, some people prefer using ternary operators.  When you set the foreground in your AddComboItem method, you can write:  "text.Foreground = _redtext ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black;"

Comment: Ah, I hadn't come across that yet (teaching myself by jumping in the deep end). Thank you.

Comment: In addition to what @WEFX said -- Even if you don't use a ternary operator, `if (_redtext == true)` is redundant. You just need `if (_redtext)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what, specifically, you're doing wrong here.  You can probably get that to work if you hack around on it enough.

But it's not the right approach - at least, not as far as writing maintainable, reliable WPF code is concerned.  You should be using data binding to populate this control.  You will find, after very little experience with doing this, that it makes for much faster, easier development than the code-WPF-as-if-it-were-WinForms approach you're taking.

Here's how:

1. Create a class for holding your data items, called, e.g. `Block`.  Have it expose string `Text` and bool `IsBanned` properties.
2. Create an `ObservableCollection<Block>` and populate it with new `Block` objects created from your data source.
3. Expose the collection to binding.  There are a lot of ways to do this; the example below assumes you've added it to the window's resource dictionary with a key of `Blocks`.  You could also implement a `Blocks` property in your window, or (what I do pretty much any time I create a window or user control in WPF) create a class that exposes a `Blocks` property and set the window's `DataContext` to an instance of that class.

Now put this in your window's XAML:

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding {DynamicResource Blocks}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBanned}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
```

You don't actually need that `Grid` in there (nor do you need to set `Grid.Column`, since it defaults to 0); I just put that in there so that the example would more accurately replicate what's in your code.  Also, I'm not setting the `Tag` property on the `ComboBoxItem`, but that's because the `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` contains the actual `Block` instance for that item, which obviates the need for the `Tag` property.

Since you're using an `ObservableCollection`, any changes that you make to the collection (i.e. adding/removing/reordering its items) will automatically be reflected in what's on the screen; binding will take care of that for you.

If the items' `Text` or `IsBanned` properties will be changing after you populate the collection, and you need the `ComboBox` to reflect these changes, you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `Block` class and have it raise `PropertyChanged` in the setters of those properties.

Comment: Your answer looks fantastic, thank you. But... As I am jumping in the deep end to find that it gets deeper a few feet away, I'm having difficulty implementing it. I'm at a loss as to where to put everything, what to call etc... Is there a handy guide that I can follow? (I've searched but there doesn't seem to be anything for someone who knows just enough to be dangerous).

Comment: A handy guide?  I wish.  Start simple, though.  Don't try to integrate the above into code you've already written:  build a small test application that only does what I outlined.  Learn how those pieces work together and then build on that knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've been most helpful.